# how to add insecure command into sudoers file securely. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I'm using sshuttle command, and ideally I'd like to use it as service or at least without entering root password.

The problem is that there is -e parameter to customize ssh invocation, which sshuttle itself warns against. But then using --sudoers-no-modify command advices to create sudoers rule:

```
(shortened by me)
me ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sshuttle *
```

Most tutorials tackles this security problem by ignoring it, but I don't like giving the user full root privileges this way. Is there a way, how to add sshuttle into sudoers file securely. For example I cannot use NOEXEC, because it needs to exec ssh. I can specify exact command line into sudoers file, but I don't know if it's sufficient not to open security hole, how exactly pattern matching works here, and if I shouldn't do it differently/better.

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[Using Sshuttle as a service](https://perfecto25.medium.com/using-sshuttle-as-a-service-bec2684a65fe).

The sshuttle client only needs sudo access to modify your firewall.
The approach described in the article avoids it and allows
non-root users to launch Ssshutle and modify the firewall's ports 12xxx.

The article is too long to summarize it here.